# Input toUpperCase con el ultimo carácter en minúscula Angular

Tags: angular, angular6

Tengo un formulario en angular en el que quiero que los caracteres se vean y se almacenen en mayúscula para lo cual tengo esta función dentro de los atributos del imput

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese los nombres del deudor" class="input is-small"
             #inputNombreRazon (input)="inputNombreRazon.value=$event.target.value.toUpperCase()"
             formControlName="DEUDOR_NOMBRES_APELLIDOS" tabindex="4">
```

Lo malo es que cuando la información se recupera, el ultimo carácter esta en minúsculas.

Alguien sabe a que se debe esta particularidad.

A continuación el constructor de mi formulario.

```
this.deudorSolidarioForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  tipo_solicitante_deudor: ['', Validators.required],
  tipo_persona_deudor: [{value: ''}],
  DEUDOR_TIPO_DOCUMENTO: ['', Validators.required],
  DEUDOR_NO_IDENTIFICACION: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15)]],
  DEUDOR_NOMBRES_APELLIDOS: ['', Validators.required],
  nombres_representante_legal: [''],
  apellidos_representante_legal: [''],
  DEUDOR_EMAIL: ['', Validators.required],
  DEUDOR_TELEFONO: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas por buen camino pero, prueba con esta linea para obtener el resultado deseado:

```html
oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"
```

Sustituye esta:

```html
(input)="inputNombreRazon.value=$event.target.value.toUpperCase()"
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias. Es justo lo que necesitaba .